# How to make quarkus find my Clojure classes?

Tags: gradle, clojure, quarkus

I want to use Quarkus with Clojure, i am using Clojurephant plugin that worked fine so far,
for example with Vert.x or [Springboot](https://github.com/tkaryadis/spring-demo). I didn't had any problems but with Quarkus it doesn't work, maybe because Quarkus classLoader?
Is there a way to say to Quakrus where to find the classes?

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joy.Interop 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) 
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) 
  at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:518) 
  at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:468) 
  at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:518) 
  at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:468) 
  ... 15 more
```

I made a simple github project to reproduce it.
https://github.com/tkaryadis/code-with-quarkus

```
./gradlew quarkusDev
```

And then, for the error

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cfrick thank you for trying to help, i added a github reproducable example, a simple quarkus project.

Comment: If you run the `test` task, the classes get picked up. So my guess is, that the quarkus gradle tooling picks not up your change to the classpath in the `compileJava` task

Comment: As was explained by @geoand on [the corresponding `github.com` issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/39277#issuecomment-1985290357): "*... We have absolutely no support for Closure and as far as I know we have never even tested it, so this is not something we will be looking into.*"

Comment: @Turing85 i saw it now,thank you. Clojure is functional, and Quarkus is based on vert.x, a functional language fits so good with functional reactive programming. I done it in Java and Clojure, in Clojure it is way easier. Maybe its not hard to allow Clojure programmers use Quarkus, in mixed java/clojure applications.

Comment: you are welcome to work on this feature in quarkus.

Comment: I think part of the problem is, that you want to have the java-code use your clj-compile-output, while the clojurephant plugin most likely is meant to be used "the other way around". Is opting out of AOT an option? Is moving the clojure into it's own gradle module and make a quarkus module depend on it an option?

Comment: @cfrick clojure dependencies seems to work fine in quarkus, the problem here is that i want to make Quarkus Clojure/Java mixed project so Clojure see Java code and the opposite. I don't know internals of Quarkus or Gradle, maybe its easy to fix, for now i am dissapointed, and i stopped trying. If anyones finds solution will be very nice, else i will retry after sometime.

Comment: My guess is, that you are to late when adding the compiled folder to the classpath; and half of the reason is, that clojurephant is meant to use clojure _after_ java is built. So using a module just for clojure and another one for quarkus, which depends on the clojure one, should work.  Also not using AOT at all and just add the `.clj` files to the resources and load them via interop should do.

Comment: thank you cfrick, after sometime i will retry, and i will try those that you suggested.